# What is the best way to multiply a column of 1500 items by itself?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, postgis

Currently I'm using Laravel and Postgres (with the extension Postgis).

I want to generate routes with 1500 different locations.

So 1500 multiplied by 1500 is 2.250.000 (This's the number of routes I want to create minus the equal locations).

**So my question is:**

1) What is the best way to do it ? (I mean creating 2.250.000 is stressful for the server)

2) What can I do to add a new location.(Because I need to update the pair with the old added locations).

3) To remove the pairs with the equal name(like Berlin and Berlin)

Comment: Just wondering why you have decided you need to create a route for every conceivable possibility? You need to read up on Routes.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Thank you for the question. The taxi service for which I work don't use km multiplied to the price, It need a static price for 80 x 80 locations and km multiplied to the price

Comment: @TimBrownlaw And I decided to make a package for OSRM, Google Maps and Mapbox users.

Comment: So you mean physical routes and not Laravel Routes

Comment: @cchoe1 Oh, sorry. Maybe I wrote it wrong. Yes, physical :)

Comment: I'm assuming you have this stored within an associative array? What are the values for each city?  A coordinate?

Comment: @cchoe1 The data is stored in Postgres(Postgis) with the columns:name,address, location(GEOGRAPHY POINT column with SRID of 4326),polygon. I can get the data in an associative array.

Comment: Sorry if link only answers are frowned upon as comments but I initially thought this would be a more general answer.  I don't really know anything about PostGIS but I did find this while I was googling: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203789/distance-from-point-stored-in-geometry-with-srid-4326

That link might be relevant for you.  It specifies some queries you can use to calculate distance between two points stored as an SRID 4326.  I was going to offer you a nested foreach loop that calculates point distance but this might be simpler.

Comment: @cchoe1 It's an way to select points in a given range, but not to match routes to each other. I have for example 6 routes(Berlin, Hamburg, Stuttgart, Hannover, Heidelberg, Bern). I need to multiply by itself, like 
Berlin - Hamburg, Berlin -Stuttgart, Berlin - Heidelberg, Berlin - Bern and then the same with the other locations, like Hamburg- Berlin, Hamburg-Stuttgart...). The problem here is the big database , with 1500 location(and even more in the future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a self-join between routes, if you want to do it naively and create the entire result set.  The best way to do it really depends on what you want to do with the result.

It sounds like you want to have a per-km charge and a flag fall charge that depends on the specific origin and destination.  Can you separate out the (origin,destination) flag fall price into fixed loadings for origin and destination that let you just associate the loadings with each location?  Then you don't need to query the entire table cross product to calculate a price.

If the pattern for the loadings can not be separated out in that way, how will these flag fall prices get loaded into your cross product matrix of locations?  There must already be a data source for this part of the pricing.

If you do want to generate the cross product, for removing duplicates, and pairs of routes like (X to Y), (Y to X), you want to use some "strictly less than" ordering comparison between the locations, which will naturally remove the reverse routes and self-routes.  Or you can use an inequality test instead to just remove the self routes and keep the reverse routes. There are suitable `WHERE` clause examples in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Self-join

Comment: Last time I used the id and do a foreach loop(so Berlin is 1 and Bern is 2 for example), then I made a relation to the price model. So for example Location id 1 name Berlin,Location id 2 name Bern. Routes id 1 from_id 1 to_id 2. Pricing id 1, route_id 1 price 200

Comment: The problem here is to use a function for getting the distance, while doing the SQL.

Comment: But It's a way. I'll try It tomorrow, maybe I'll store the distance in a new table.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you want to insert, hopefully this approach will work for you:

```
public function insert_locations($locations, $new_locations) {

    // make them into collection if not already
    $locations_coll = Collection::make($locations);

    // chunk the database insert if there are too many records in the collection
    $locations_coll->chunk(500)->each(function($chunk1) {

        $inserts = '';
        // loop through locations
        foreach($chunk1 as $location1) {

            foreach($new_locations as $location2) {

                // if locations are the same then skip
                if($location1==$location2) continue;

                // add to bulk inserts
                $inserts .= '(' . $location1 . '-' . $location2 . '), ' . PHP_EOL;
            }

        }

        // do the bulk insert
        try {
            DB::insert("INSERT INTO your_table (`locations`) VALUES $inserts");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print_r([$e->getMessage()]);
        }
    });
}

// get your existing locations
$locations = ['Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Stuttgart', 'Hannover', 'Heidelberg', 'Bern' ...];

// and get your new locations
$new_locations = ['Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Stuttgart', 'Hannover', 'Heidelberg', 'Bern' ...];

// call the method
insert_locations($locations, $new_locations);

// get more new locations
$new_locations = ['Bayern'];

// call the method again
insert_locations($locations, $new_locations);
```

If you want to avoid inserting duplicates you could use something like this in your sql statement:

```
DB::insert("INSERT INTO your_table (`locations`) VALUES $inserts ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `locations`=VALUES(`locations`)");
```

Comment: The problem, what would happen, if I add a new location? For example I add Bayern to It.

Comment: I have updated my my answer to try and accommodate this. Though I may not be understanding what you need.